# jquery access function/plugin in a different file without using a selector

Tags: jquery

I cant figure out why I am getting the error:

> Error: TypeError: $.showMessage is not a function

File 1:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showMessage = function(message, type, delay) {
        var $messages = $("#messages");
        type = (typeof type == 'undefined') ? 'info' : type;
        delay = (typeof delay == 'undefined') ? 0 : delay;

        var message_html = '<div class="messages"><ul>' +
                                '<li class="'+ type +'">' +
                                '<p>' + message + '</p><a href="#" class="close"></a>' +
                            '</li></ul></div>';         

        if($messages.length){
            $messages.html(message_html).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn("fast");
        } else {
            $("#main h1").before(message_html).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn("fast");
        }
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

File 2:

```
(function($) {
    $.showMessage('test','success');
})(jQuery);
```

Note: it works fine if I have a each() and use a selector `$("#messages").showMessage('test','success');`. I read somewhere that you always need to return `this` although can't figure how to do this without the each()

The below version works fine, although do I really need the each and to pass a selector?

```
$.fn.showMessage = function(message, type, delay) {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
        type = (typeof type == 'undefined') ? 'info' : type;
        delay = (typeof delay == 'undefined') ? 0 : delay;

        var message_html = '<div class="messages"><ul>' +
                                '<li class="'+ type +'">' +
                                '<p>' + message + '</p><a href="#" class="close"></a>' +
                            '</li></ul></div>';         

        if($this.length){
            $this.html(message_html).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn("fast");
        } else {
            $("#main h1").before(message_html).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn("fast");
        }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the construct `$.fn.showMessage`, you are declaring a jQuery plugin named `showMessage` that will act on a given [context](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), e.g., `$("#main").showMessage`. To declare a *plugin* that can be called in a *static* way, that is, a helper method, you need to declare it *outside* of the `$.fn` namespace:

```
(function($) {
    $.showMessage = function(message, type, delay) {
      // ...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it now. Didn't realise that the 'fn' part did this. Just to the confirm, does it matter if I return true or does this need to always return jquery?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia: It doesn't need to return a jQuery object since it's not a jQuery *plugin* per se, and the definition of *chainability* doesn't apply. It's more like an utility function defined in the `$` namespace. jQuery provides several of those http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/, such as `$.now` and `$.trim`.